# Get all available fields in plugin setting page

Tags: plugin-development, entries-field

I am trying to get all the `fields` created by admin in my custom plugin setting page.

As we can get entries , in same way can we have option to get the available fields.

```
 {{ forms.elementSelectField({
    label: 'Entry Select Field',
    id: 'entries',
    name: '',
    elementType: 'craft\\elements\\Entry',
    elements: [craft.entries.one()],
    selectionLabel: 'Select an entry',

}) }}
```

> I tried to look in core file :/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Fields.php

```
$fields = Craft::$app->fields->getAllFields();
```

But there is no such method which return the list of existing fields.

Update:

Now i am able to get the list of all the existing fields.

```
$fieldsData = [];

$fields = Craft::$app->fields->getAllFields();

foreach ($fields as $field)
{

    $fieldsData['name'][] = $field->name;
    $fieldsData['handle'][] = $field->handle;
}
```

In setting the template of plugin I want to give admin an option to select multi fields `(handles )` on the plugin setting page. For this, I am trying to fetch all the created fields first and then pass that array to form micro so that it can populate the multi-select.

> But can we populate multi-select like?

```
{{ forms.multiselectField({
    label: 'Multi Select Field',
    name: '',
    options: {
      fields['handle']: fields['name'],  
    },
    values: '',
}) }}
```

> Or if we create our custom multi-select fields how we can save the user ( admin) input? as in micro, it saves by itself.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve? Maybe the multi-select documentation is helpful: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/multi-select-fields.html#templating

Comment: I want to give admin an option to select multi fields `(handles )` on the plugin setting page. For this i am trying to fetch all the created fields first and then pass that array to form micro so that it can populate the multi-select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the created fields first and encode them.

```
protected function settingsHtml(): string
{
    $fieldsData = [];
    $fields = Craft::$app->fields->getAllFields();
    foreach ($fields as $field)
    {
        $fieldsData[$field->handle] = $field->name;
    }

}
```

In settings.twig template

```
{{ forms.multiselectField({
    label: 'Select Fields',
    name: 'fieldSelected',
    id: 'fieldSelected',
    required:     true,
    options: fields,
    values: settings['fieldSelected']
}) }}
```

Output:

[image: select fields]

Answer (score 1):

The fields service **does** include a method getAllFields:

```
$fields = Craft::$app->fields->getAllFields(false);
```